# How do I use Times/Times Roman/Times New Roman in LaTex?

Tags: fonts

Ive been using LaTeX for a few days and have written up my entire document but am unable to change the font to any variant of Times/Times Roman/Times New Roman. I swapped from MS word on the recommendation of a friend and am absolutely loving it, especially the BibTex aspect. I am on a Mac using TeXShop.

I have tried using

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

but neither changes the font.

My preamble consists of

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}       
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=25mm,
 }                      
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           
\usepackage{graphicx}                                               
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.4cm plus4mm minus3mm}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\Mypm}{\mathbin{\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.1ex] \draw (0.0,0) -- (1.0,0) (0.5,0.08) -- (0.5,0.92) (0.0,0.5) -- (1.0,0.5);}}%
\title{Influence}
\author{}
\date{}                         % Activate to display a given date or no date
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\onehalfspacing
```

Comment: you made times the default roman font but then `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` makes the document sans serif, just delete that line

Comment: Using LaTeX before TL2015 `fixltx2e` should be loaded as first Package even before the documentclass with `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}`, see http://www.texdev.net/2014/12/28/fixing-latex2e/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It is a good idea not to copy some preamble commands unless you know what they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get rid of the instruction

  ```
  \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
  ```

  Times Roman is a font with serifs. What good is supposed to come from selecting a sans-serif font as the main text font?
- Replace the instruction

  ```
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
  ```

  with

  ```
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
  ```
- Other comments about your preamble:

  - A4 paper is, I believe, 210mm wide and 297mm tall. Thus, the second argument of the `\geometry` directive -- `total={210mm,297mm}` -- is redundant.
  - Still on the `\geometry` directive: If all four margins are supposed to be equal to 25mm, it suffices to provide the option `margin=25mm`.
  - No point loading the `graphicx` package twice, is there?